# mongodb belongsTo Foreign key is null

Tags: strongloop, loopbackjs

So this question feels a lot like my last one. Strongloop is making me feel like such a noob. lol.

I stole this from some of the LB examples:

```
var Order = mongoDev.createModel('order', {
    customerId: Number,
    orderDesc: String
});

var Customer = mongoDev.createModel('customer', {
    id: {type: Number, id: true},
    name: String,
    emails: [String],
    age: Number},
  {strcit: true});

//Order.belongsTo(Customer);
Order.belongsTo(Customer, {as: 'customer', foreignKey: 'customerId'});
Customer.hasMany(Order, {as: 'orders', foreignKey: 'customerId'});
```

In the explorer I see both the customer & order endpoints. Also customers has endpoints for `/customers/{id}/orders` and orders has `/orders/{id}/customer` etc. So far so good.

I have this customer added:

```
GET .../api/customers/53c599594e23e50000a41acf
{
  "id": "53c599594e23e50000a41acf",
  "name": "John1",
  "emails": [
    "john@x.com",
    "jhon@y.com"
  ],
  "age": 30
}
```

When I post an order I get a null customerId:

```
POST .../api/customers/53c599594e23e50000a41acf/orders
    data: {"orderDesc": "whatever"}

result:
{
  "customerId": null,
  "orderDesc": "whatever",
  "id": "53c59d1efd31a4000062e7d8"
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769790/mongodb-belongsto-foreign-key-is-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, solved this. The examples I stole from had the Id's typed as Numbers. Changing those to Strings fixed this problem for me.

```
var Order = mongoDev.createModel('order', {
    customerId: String,
    orderDesc: String
});

var Customer = mongoDev.createModel('customer', {
    id: {type: String, id: true},
    name: String,
    emails: [String],
    age: Number},
  {strcit: true});
```